# Raspbian Buster won't connect to network unless the console is displayed

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

We get to the point where I really don't know what to fix now.

Basically, I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Buster, and I don't know why but connecting to the network, make it wifi or wired, does not seems to work unless I actually connect a keyboard and a display to it.

Basic scenario is as follow :

1. I configure the network connecting a keyboard and a display.
2. Check that the configuration is working correctly by rebooting the RPI
   both gracefuly (ie: `sudo reboot now`) and forcefully (ie: unplug)
3. Keyboard and display connected, everything is fine (showing in rooter attached devices and can connect to web service hosted on it: *Domoticz*).
4. Now I turn off the display, disconnect the keyboard Connect to RPI using SSH from
   another computer.
5. `sudo reboot now`
6. Looking in the rooter attached devices, the RPI does not show anymore. SSH connection is not possible anymore.

And this is repeatable, it's not like it happens from time to time. Everytime I run the described scenario I have this issue.

If somebody could give me an idea of where to look to eventually understand what's happening, that'd be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try ro :
1- if you connected with Wireless . should configure SSID and password in "wpa_supplicant" file.
2- configure static ip address.
3- configure ssh service for start at boot.